# ScrollToView horizontal in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I have a horizontal row of items that is scrollable. On selection of item from another button, I'd like to scroll and show the currently selected item. ScrollToView is currently not working for me.

component.html

```
 <div>
  <h1>Hi {{ name }}</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div
    [class.active]="selected === item"
    (click)="select(item)"
    *ngFor="let item of items" class="item">
      {{ 'item-' + item }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="select(1)">select 1</button>
  <button (click)="select(5)">select 5</button>
  <button (click)="select(8)">select 8</button>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
export class App {
  name: string;
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  selected: number;

  select(item){
    this.selected = item
    const el = document.querySelector('.active')
    if(el) el.scrollIntoView()
  }

}
```

component.css

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/lTlJKin4WmwBlJrD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ViewChildren, for example:

```
@ViewChildren("element", { read: ElementRef }) elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

put template-reference variable "#element"

```
<div
  #element
  *ngFor="let item of items"
  (click)="select(item)"
  [class.active]="selected === item"
  class="item"
 >
  {{ 'item-' + item }}
</div>
```

now iterate the elements to find the element and call "scrollIntoView()"

```
  select(selected: number): void {
    this.selected = selected;
    this.elements.forEach((element, i) => {
      if (selected === i) {
        element.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "nearest",
          inline: "end"
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I created an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4wwcfq)